# how to use yarn to install swal

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, yarnpkg

I'm new to yarn.

So I've my rails 5.1 application with yarn, I want to add this package:

https://yarnpkg.com/en/package/swal

So I do:

```
yarn add swal
```

it got added to `node-modules/swal` a lot of files but not the js that I should require.

I go to that folder and do `npm install`.

but I still dont have my swal.js to include...

I read the README and it says to run `npm run build`, it throws a dependency with vue error.

So I start to wonder.. I 've to investigate how to build each JS? Is that better than just get the .js already compiled and put it on `vendor` folder?

Anyway my question here is concrete, what is the way to add swal.

Comment: Use `yarn install` in order to include your dependencies into your node modules folder. Offical documentation [here](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install)

Comment: Ok, and then? I need to build one by one my modules? because doing `yarn install` does not generates the file I can include on my application, and actually, at least for swal, when i run `npm run build` on the swal folder it throws an error.